# Marginal Likelihood from the Gibbs Output

Tags: bayesian, mixture-distribution, gibbs

I'm reproducing from scratch the results in Section 4.2.1 of

**[Marginal Likelihood from the Gibbs Output](http://apps.olin.wustl.edu/faculty/chib/papers/chib95.pdf)**

*Siddhartha Chib*

Journal of the American Statistical Association, Vol. 90, No. 432. (Dec., 1995), pp. 1313-1321.

It's a mixture of normals model with known number $k\geq 1$ of components. 
$$
  f(x\mid w,\mu,\sigma^2) =\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k \mathrm{N}(x_i\mid\mu_j,\sigma_j^2) \, . \qquad (*)
$$

The Gibbs sampler for this model is implemented using the data augmentation technique of Tanner and Wong. A set of allocation variables $z=(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ assuming the values $1,\dots,k$ is introduced, and we specify that $\Pr(z_i=j\mid w)=w_j$ and $f(x_i\mid z,\mu,\sigma^2)=\mathrm{N}(x_i\mid\mu_{z_i},\sigma^2_{z_i})$. It follows that integration over the $z_i$'s gives the original likelihood $(*)$.

The dataset is formed by velocities of $82$ galaxies from the Corona Borealis constellation.

```
set.seed(1701)

x <- c(  9.172,  9.350,  9.483,  9.558,  9.775, 10.227, 10.406, 16.084, 16.170, 18.419, 18.552, 18.600, 18.927,
        19.052, 19.070, 19.330, 19.343, 19.349, 19.440, 19.473, 19.529, 19.541, 19.547, 19.663, 19.846, 19.856,
        19.863, 19.914, 19.918, 19.973, 19.989, 20.166, 20.175, 20.179, 20.196, 20.215, 20.221, 20.415, 20.629,
        20.795, 20.821, 20.846, 20.875, 20.986, 21.137, 21.492, 21.701, 21.814, 21.921, 21.960, 22.185, 22.209,
        22.242, 22.249, 22.314, 22.374, 22.495, 22.746, 22.747, 22.888, 22.914, 23.206, 23.241, 23.263, 23.484,
        23.538, 23.542, 23.666, 23.706, 23.711, 24.129, 24.285, 24.289, 24.366, 24.717, 24.990, 25.633, 26.960,
        26.995, 32.065, 32.789, 34.279 )

nn <- length(x)
```

We assume that $w$, the $\mu_j$'s, and the $\sigma^2_j$'s are independent *a priori* with
$$
   (w_1,\dots,w_k) \sim \mathrm{Dir}(a_1,\dots,a_k) \, , \quad
  \mu_j \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu_0,\sigma_0^2) \, , \quad \sigma^2_j\sim\mathrm{IG}\!\left(\frac{\nu_0}{2},\frac{\delta_0}{2}\right) \, .
$$

```
k <- 3

mu0 <- 20
va0 <- 100

nu0 <- 6
de0 <- 40

a <- rep(1, k)
```

Using Bayes' Theorem, the full conditionals are
$$
\begin{align*}
  w \mid \mu,\sigma^2,z,x &\sim \mathrm{Dir}(a_1+n_1,\dots,a_k+n_k) \\
  \mu_j \mid w, \sigma^2,z,x &\sim \mathrm{N}\!\left( \frac{n_j m_j\sigma_0^2+\mu_0\sigma_j^2}{n_j\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_j}, \frac{\sigma^2_0\sigma^2_j}{n_j\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_j}\right) \\
  \sigma_j^2 \mid w,\mu,z,x &\sim \mathrm{IG}\!\left( \frac{\nu_0+n_j}{2},\frac{\delta_0+\delta_j}{2}\right) \\
  \Pr(z_i=j\mid w,\mu,\sigma^2,x) &\propto w_j \times \frac{1}{\sigma_j}e^{-(x_i-\mu_j)^2/2\sigma_j^2}
\end{align*}
$$
in which
$$
  n_j = |L_j| \, , \qquad 
  m_j = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n_j}\sum_{i\in L_j} x_i &\;\mathrm{if}\; n_j>0 \\ 0 &\;\mathrm{otherwise.} \end{cases}\, , \qquad
  \delta_j = \sum_{i\in L_j} (x_i-\mu_j)^2 \, ,
$$
with $L_j=\{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}:z_i=j\}$.

The goal is to compute an estimate for the marginal likelihood of the model. Chib's method begins with a first run of the Gibbs sampler using the full conditionals.

```
burn_in <- 1000
run     <- 15000

cat("First Gibbs run (full):\n")

N <- burn_in + run

w  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = k)
mu <- matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = k)
va <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = k)
z  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = nn)

n <- integer(k)
m <- numeric(k)
de <- numeric(k)

rdirichlet <- function(a) { y <- rgamma(length(a), a, 1); y / sum(y) }

pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 2, max = N, style = 3)
z[1,] <- sample.int(k, size = nn, replace = TRUE)
for (t in 2:N) {
    n <- tabulate(z[t-1,], nbins = k)
    w[t,] <- rdirichlet(a + n)
    m <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(x[z[t-1,]==j]))
    m[n > 0] <- m[n > 0] / n[n > 0]
    mu[t,] <- rnorm(k, mean = (n*m*va0+mu0*va[t-1,])/(n*va0+va[t-1,]), sd = sqrt(va0*va[t-1,]/(n*va0+va[t-1,])))
    de <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum((x[z[t-1,]==j] - mu[t,j])^2))
    va[t,] <- 1 / rgamma(k, shape = (nu0+n)/2, rate = (de0+de)/2)
    z[t,] <- sapply(1:nn, function(i) sample.int(k, size = 1, prob = exp(log(w[t,]) + dnorm(x[i], mean = mu[t,], sd = sqrt(va[t,]), log = TRUE))))
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, t)
}
close(pb)
```

From this first run we get an approximate point $(w^*,\mu^*,\sigma^{2*})$ of maximum likelihood. Since the likelihood is actually unbounded, what this procedure probably gives is an approximate local MAP.

```
w  <- w[(burn_in+1):N,]
mu <- mu[(burn_in+1):N,]
va <- va[(burn_in+1):N,]
z  <- z[(burn_in+1):N,]
N  <- N - burn_in

log_L <- function(x, w, mu, va) sum(log(sapply(1:nn, function(i) sum(exp(log(w) + dnorm(x[i], mean = mu, sd = sqrt(va), log = TRUE))))))

ts <- which.max(sapply(1:N, function(t) log_L(x, w[t,], mu[t,], va[t,])))

ws <- w[ts,]
mus <- mu[ts,]
vas <- va[ts,]
```

Chib's log-estimate of the marginal likelihood is
$$
\begin{align}
  \log \widehat{f(x)} &= \log L_x(w^*,\mu^*,\sigma^{2*}) + \log \pi(w^*,\mu^*,\sigma^{2*}) \\
  &- \log \pi(\mu^*\mid x) - \log \pi(\sigma^{2*}\mid \mu^*,x) - \log \pi(w^*\mid \mu^*,\sigma^{2*},x) \, .
\end{align}
$$

We already have the first two terms.

```
log_prior <- function(w, mu, va) {
    lgamma(sum(a)) - sum(lgamma(a)) + sum((a-1)*log(w))
    + sum(dnorm(mu, mean = mu0, sd = sqrt(va0), log = TRUE))
    + sum((nu0/2)*log(de0/2) - lgamma(nu0/2) - (nu0/2+1)*log(va) - de0/(2*va))
}

chib <- log_L(x, ws, mus, vas) + log_prior(ws, mus, vas)
```

The Rao-Blackwellized estimate of $\pi(\mu^*\mid x)$ is
$$
  \pi(\mu^*\mid x) = \int \prod_{j=1}^k \mathrm{N}\!\left(\mu_j^* \;\Bigg|\; \frac{n_j m_j\sigma_0^2+\mu_0\sigma_j^2}{n_j\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_j}, \frac{\sigma^2_0\sigma^2_j}{n_j\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_j}\right)\,p(\sigma^{2},z\mid x)\,d\sigma^2\,dz \, ,
$$
and is readily obtained from the first Gibbs run.

```
pi.mu_va.z.x <- function(mu, va, z) {
    n <- tabulate(z, nbins = k)
    m <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(x[z==j]))
    m[n > 0] <- m[n > 0] / n[n > 0]
    exp(sum(dnorm(mu, mean = (n*m*va0+mu0*va)/(n*va0+va), sd = sqrt(va0*va/(n*va0+va)), log = TRUE)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.mu_va.z.x(mus, va[t,], z[t,]))))
```

The Rao-Blackwellized estimate of $\pi(\sigma^{2*}\mid \mu^*,x)$ is
$$
  \pi(\sigma^{2*}\mid \mu^*,x) = \int \prod_{j=1}^k \mathrm{IG}\!\left( \sigma^{2*}_j \;\Bigg|\; \frac{\nu_0+n_j}{2},\frac{\delta_0+\delta_j}{2}\right) \, p(z\mid\mu^*,x)\,dz \, ,
$$
and is computed from a second reduced Gibbs run in which the $\mu_j$'s are not updated, but made equal to $\mu^*_j$ at each iteration step.

```
cat("Second Gibbs run (reduced):\n")

N <- burn_in + run

w  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = k)
va <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = k)
z  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = nn) 

pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 2, max = N, style = 3)
z[1,] <- sample.int(k, size = nn, replace = TRUE)
for (t in 2:N) {
    n <- tabulate(z[t-1,], nbins = k)
    w[t,] <- rdirichlet(a + n)
    de <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum((x[z[t-1,]==j] - mus[j])^2))
    va[t,] <- 1 / rgamma(k, shape = (nu0+n)/2, rate = (de0+de)/2)
    z[t,] <- sapply(1:nn, function(i) sample.int(k, size = 1, prob = exp(log(w[t,]) + dnorm(x[i], mean = mus, sd = sqrt(va[t,]), log = TRUE))))
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, t)
}
close(pb)

w  <- w[(burn_in+1):N,]
va <- va[(burn_in+1):N,]
z  <- z[(burn_in+1):N,]
N  <- N - burn_in

pi.va_mu.z.x <- function(va, mu, z) {
    n <- tabulate(z, nbins = k)         
    de <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum((x[z==j] - mu[j])^2))
    exp(sum(((nu0+n)/2)*log((de0+de)/2) - lgamma((nu0+n)/2) - ((nu0+n)/2+1)*log(va) - (de0+de)/(2*va)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.va_mu.z.x(vas, mus, z[t,]))))
```

In the same way, the Rao-Blackwellized estimate of $\pi(w^*\mid \mu^*,\sigma^{2*},x)$ is
$$
  \pi(w^*\mid \mu^*,\sigma^{2*},x) = \int \mathrm{Dir}(w^* \mid a_1+n_1,\dots,a_k+n_k) \, p(z\mid\mu^*,\sigma^{2*},x)\,dz \, ,
$$
and is computed from a third reduced Gibbs run in which the $\mu_j$'s and the $\sigma^2_j$'s are not updated, but made equal to $\mu^*_j$ and $\sigma^{2*}_j$ respectively at each iteration step.

```
cat("Third Gibbs run (reduced):\n")

N <- burn_in + run

w  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = k)
z  <- matrix(1, nrow = N, ncol = nn) 

pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 2, max = N, style = 3)
z[1,] <- sample.int(k, size = nn, replace = TRUE)
for (t in 2:N) {
    n <- tabulate(z[t-1,], nbins = k)
    w[t,] <- rdirichlet(a + n)
    z[t,] <- sapply(1:nn, function(i) sample.int(k, size = 1, prob = exp(log(w[t,]) + dnorm(x[i], mean = mus, sd = sqrt(vas), log = TRUE))))
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, t)
}
close(pb)

w  <- w[(burn_in+1):N,]
z  <- z[(burn_in+1):N,]
N  <- N - burn_in

pi.w_z.x <- function(w, z) {
    n <- tabulate(z, nbins = k)
    exp(lgamma(sum(a+n)) - sum(lgamma(a+n)) + sum((a+n-1)*log(w)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.w_z.x(ws, z[t,]))))
```

After all this, we get a log-estimate $-217.9199$ which is bigger than the one reported by Chib: $-224.138$ with Monte Carlo error $.086$.

To check if I somehow messed up the Gibbs samplers, I reimplemented the whole thing using RJAGS. The following code gives the same results.

```
x <- c( 9.172,  9.350,  9.483,  9.558,  9.775, 10.227, 10.406, 16.084, 16.170, 18.419, 18.552, 18.600, 18.927, 19.052, 19.070, 19.330,
       19.343, 19.349, 19.440, 19.473, 19.529, 19.541, 19.547, 19.663, 19.846, 19.856, 19.863, 19.914, 19.918, 19.973, 19.989, 20.166,
       20.175, 20.179, 20.196, 20.215, 20.221, 20.415, 20.629, 20.795, 20.821, 20.846, 20.875, 20.986, 21.137, 21.492, 21.701, 21.814,
       21.921, 21.960, 22.185, 22.209, 22.242, 22.249, 22.314, 22.374, 22.495, 22.746, 22.747, 22.888, 22.914, 23.206, 23.241, 23.263,
       23.484, 23.538, 23.542, 23.666, 23.706, 23.711, 24.129, 24.285, 24.289, 24.366, 24.717, 24.990, 25.633, 26.960, 26.995, 32.065,
       32.789, 34.279 )

library(rjags)

nn <- length(x)

k <- 3

mu0 <- 20
va0 <- 100

nu0 <- 6
de0 <- 40

a <- rep(1, k)

burn_in <- 10^3

N <- 10^4

full <- "
    model {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            x[i] ~ dnorm(mu[z[i]], tau[z[i]])
            z[i] ~ dcat(w[])
        }
        for (i in 1:k) {
            mu[i] ~ dnorm(mu0, 1/va0)
            tau[i] ~ dgamma(nu0/2, de0/2)
            va[i] <- 1/tau[i]
        }
        w ~ ddirich(a)
    }
"
data <- list(x = x, n = nn, k = k, mu0 = mu0, va0 = va0, nu0 = nu0, de0 = de0, a = a)
model <- jags.model(textConnection(full), data = data, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 100)
update(model, n.iter = burn_in)
samples <- jags.samples(model, c("mu", "va", "w", "z"), n.iter = N)

mu <- matrix(samples$mu, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
    va <- matrix(samples$va, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
w <- matrix(samples$w, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
    z <- matrix(samples$z, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)

log_L <- function(x, w, mu, va) sum(log(sapply(1:nn, function(i) sum(exp(log(w) + dnorm(x[i], mean = mu, sd = sqrt(va), log = TRUE))))))

ts <- which.max(sapply(1:N, function(t) log_L(x, w[t,], mu[t,], va[t,])))

ws <- w[ts,]
mus <- mu[ts,]
vas <- va[ts,]

log_prior <- function(w, mu, va) {
    lgamma(sum(a)) - sum(lgamma(a)) + sum((a-1)*log(w))
    + sum(dnorm(mu, mean = mu0, sd = sqrt(va0), log = TRUE))
    + sum((nu0/2)*log(de0/2) - lgamma(nu0/2) - (nu0/2+1)*log(va) - de0/(2*va))
}

chib <- log_L(x, ws, mus, vas) + log_prior(ws, mus, vas)

cat("log-likelihood + log-prior =", chib, "\n")

pi.mu_va.z.x <- function(mu, va, z, x) {
    n <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(z==j))
    m <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(x[z==j]))
    m[n > 0] <- m[n > 0] / n[n > 0]
    exp(sum(dnorm(mu, mean = (n*m*va0+mu0*va)/(n*va0+va), sd = sqrt(va0*va/(n*va0+va)), log = TRUE)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.mu_va.z.x(mus, va[t,], z[t,], x))))

cat("log-likelihood + log-prior - log-pi.mu_ =", chib, "\n")

fixed.mu <- "
    model {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            x[i] ~ dnorm(mus[z[i]], tau[z[i]])
            z[i] ~ dcat(w[])
        }
        for (i in 1:k) {
            tau[i] ~ dgamma(nu0/2, de0/2)
            va[i] <- 1/tau[i]
        }
        w ~ ddirich(a)
    }
"
data <- list(x = x, n = nn, k = k, nu0 = nu0, de0 = de0, a = a, mus = mus)
model <- jags.model(textConnection(fixed.mu), data = data, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 100)
update(model, n.iter = burn_in)
samples <- jags.samples(model, c("va", "w", "z"), n.iter = N)

va <- matrix(samples$va, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
    w <- matrix(samples$w, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
z <- matrix(samples$z, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)

pi.va_mu.z.x <- function(va, mu, z, x) {
    n <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(z==j))
    de <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum((x[z==j] - mu[j])^2))
    exp(sum(((nu0+n)/2)*log((de0+de)/2) - lgamma((nu0+n)/2) - ((nu0+n)/2+1)*log(va) - (de0+de)/(2*va)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.va_mu.z.x(vas, mus, z[t,], x))))

cat("log-likelihood + log-prior - log-pi.mu_ - log-pi.va_ =", chib, "\n")

fixed.mu.and.va <- "
    model {
        for (i in 1:n) {
            x[i] ~ dnorm(mus[z[i]], 1/vas[z[i]])
            z[i] ~ dcat(w[])
        }
        w ~ ddirich(a)
    }
"
data <- list(x = x, n = nn, a = a, mus = mus, vas = vas)
model <- jags.model(textConnection(fixed.mu.and.va), data = data, n.chains = 1, n.adapt = 100)
update(model, n.iter = burn_in)
samples <- jags.samples(model, c("w", "z"), n.iter = N)

w <- matrix(samples$w, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)
    z <- matrix(samples$z, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE)

pi.w_z.x <- function(w, z, x) {
    n <- sapply(1:k, function(j) sum(z==j))
    exp(lgamma(sum(a)+nn) - sum(lgamma(a+n)) + sum((a+n-1)*log(w)))
}

chib <- chib - log(mean(sapply(1:N, function(t) pi.w_z.x(ws, z[t,], x))))

cat("log-likelihood + log-prior - log-pi.mu_ - log-pi.va_ - log-pi.w_ =", chib, "\n")
```

My question is if in the above description there are any misunderstandings of Chib's method or any mistakes in its implementation.

Comment: Running the simulation 100 times, the results are in the range $[-218.7655; -216.8824]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a slight programming mistake in the prior

```
log_prior <- function(w, mu, va) {
    lgamma(sum(a)) - sum(lgamma(a)) + sum((a-1)*log(w))
    + sum(dnorm(mu, mean = mu0, sd = sqrt(va0), log = TRUE))
    + sum((nu0/2)*log(de0/2) - lgamma(nu0/2) - (nu0/2+1)*log(va) - de0/(2*va))
}
```

as it should be instead

```
log_prior <- function(w, mu, va) {
    lgamma(sum(a)) - sum(lgamma(a)) + sum((a-1)*log(w)) +
      sum(dnorm(mu, mean = mu0, sd = sqrt(va0), log = TRUE)) +
      sum((nu0/2)*log(de0/2) - lgamma(nu0/2) - (nu0/2+1)*log(va) - de0/(2*va))
}
```

Rerunning the code this way leads to

```
> chib
[1] -228.194
```

which is *not* the value produced in Chib (1995) for that case! However, in [Neal](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~radford/ftp/chib-letter.pdf)'s (1999) reanalysis of the problem, he mentions that

> According to one anonymous JASA referee, the figure of -224.138 for 
>   the log of the marginal likelihood for the three component model with
>   unequal variances that was given in Chib's paper is a "typo" wtih the
>   correct figure being -228.608.

So this solves the discrepancy issue.

Comment: Prof. Christian Robert and Kate Lee: do you know how great you are?

Comment: By the way, this is definitely an example of "evil syntax". I won't forget this one.