# Can MCMC algorithm estimate partition function (normalizing constant)?

Tags: estimation, markov-chain-montecarlo

Importance Sampling can estimated the normalizing constant by averaging the weights (the ratio of unnoramlized distribution and importance distribution). Is there anyway that MCMC algorithm can estimate the normalizing constant as well?

Comment: The most common way is Charles Geyers' reverse logistic regression method, which is published as a [Tech Report here](https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/58433).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I produced [a detailed answer to an earlier X validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/210196/7224), let me recall here that there are [many ways](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2016/05/19/using-mcmc-output-to-efficiently-estimate-bayes-factors/) of approximating the normalising constant, besides [importance sampling](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1028905934):

1. [Chib's](https://stat.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/NormConstants/ChibJASA1995.pdf) (1994) (or the candidate's) formula
2. Gelfand and Dey's (1995) representation, which includes the [infamous harmonic mean estimator](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/)
3. [particle filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter) and sequential Monte Carlo
4. [nested sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_sampling_algorithm)
5. [reversible jump MCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible-jump_Markov_chain_Monte_Carlo)
6. [path sampling](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1028905934) or [thermodynamic integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_integration)
7. [bridge sampling](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1028905934)
8. [Geyer's](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.6450) (1994) logistic regression
9. the [Savage-Dickey representation](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/24/is-the-dickey-savage-ratio-any-valid/)

some of which are unbiased and most of which are described in [Chen, Shao and Ibrahim (2001)](https://amzn.to/2GnqAkj).